# Как сделать такую яндекс разметку для карты?

Tags: яндекс-карты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ест стандартная яндекс карта, обычное состояние такое . Вопрос как их добавить + при клике открывались полноценный фотографии. И возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выглядит как геометки с открытыми балунами. Вообще, с балунами такая история:

"Балун — всплывающее облако, которое может отображать любое HTML-содержимое. **Обычно балун существует на карте в единственном экземпляре**" (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/ )

И вот тут: https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/24098 пишут, что "интерфейс проектировали с учетом того, что **балун на карте один и открытие нового закрывает старый**".

В качестве решения можно рассмотреть метки со своим HTML макетом. Вот пример в песочнице: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape

Можно сделать и реакцию на клик, для этого нужно задать активную область:

Метка, чтобы ловить события мышки, использует активную область. По умолчанию при задании своего HTML макета фигура активной области не задается, и её нужно задать самостоятельно. Это можно сделать при помощи опции метки iconShape в виде JSON описания геометрии. Подробнее вот тут:
(https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/layouts-docpage/ ).